# Nested For Each Statement

Tags: vba, excel

Good Morning All,

I'm using the Advanced Example from the [VBA-JSON Parser](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) to load JSON files into excel. It works fine, but I'd like to change a bit of code to iterate through a string array instead of spelling each item out.

Here's the part I'd like to change:

```
Dim Value As Dictionary
Dim i As Long

i = 0
For Each Value In Parsed("values")
  Values(i, 0) = Value("a")
  Values(i, 1) = Value("b")
  Values(i, 2) = Value("c")
  i = i + 1
Next Value

Sheets("example").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Parsed("values").Count, 3)) = Values
```

Instead of spelling out each value ("a", "b", "c"), I'd like it to just run through each item I have in my string array while it's iterating through each value in the parsed list.

This is the string array I have:

```
Dim ParentArray As Variant

ParentArray = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

I imagine it's something like this, but I'm not sure how to make it work...

```
i = 0
For Each Value In Parsed(parent)
    n = 1
        For Each ArrItem In ParentArray
            ArrItem = (ParentArray(1, n))
            Values(i, n - 1) = Value(ArrItem)
            n = n + 1
        Next ArrItem
    i = i + 1
Next Value

Sheets(parent).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Parsed(parent).Count, ColCount)) = Values
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Phillip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have it correct, it's just a matter of syntax:

```
For Each Value In Parsed(parent)
    n = 1
        For j = LBound(ParentArray) to UBound(ParentArray)
            Values(i, n - 1) = Value(ParentArray(j))
            n = n + 1
        Next j
    i = i + 1
Next Value
```

Comment: Probably safer to use `LBound` instead of assuming the array always starts at 0.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for the help (I was sooooo close...)